# How to fit polynomial into some error bars data

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I need to fit data e.g. x, y, CI (where CI is confidence index of y) in Matlab.

Now, I use this code:

```
pf = polyfit(x, y, 2);
x1 = min(x):.1:max(x);
y1 = polyval(pf, x1);

figure
hold on
errorbar(x, y, CI, 'ko');
plot(x1, y1, 'k');
hold off
```

Of course, the fit comes out of some errors bars, and it's correct.

I would like obtain a fit curve closer to the points with a low confidence index, and discard the points with a high confidence index.

Thank you and bye,
*Giacomo*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for are *Weighted Least Squares*. You can compute them with the function `lscov`. There is a nice example in its help page, but I'll try to make it clearer.

Let us construct a simple parabola, with a corrupted point

```
x = (0:0.1:1)';
y = 0.5*x.^2;
y(5) = 3*y(5);
```

and give some weights

```
w = ones(size(y));
w(5) = 0.1;
```

Next build the Vandermonde matrix ([see here for the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27903958/3676517)) and solve the system

```
%// V = [x.^2 x ones(size(x))];
V = bsxfun(@power, x, 2:-1:0);
coeff = lscov(V, y, w);
```

The estimated coefficients, with and without the weights, are

```
                x^2       x        1
 with weights  [0.4797    0.0186   -0.0004]
 no weights    [0.3322    0.1533   -0.0034]
```

Note that in your case `w` will have to be inverted.

If you don't like to build the Vandermonde matrix, and you have a license for the Curve Fitting Toolbox, you can use the following code

```
ft = fittype('poly2');
opts = fitoptions('Method', 'LinearLeastSquares');
opts.Weights = w;
fitresult = fit(x, y, ft, opts);
```

and you'll obtain the same result.

Comment: Thank you, Jommy. Tomorrow I'll try your solutions. Thank you for your explanation, too.