# Calculating x, x.^2,...x.^K (vectorization of powers,geometric series) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

Let `x` be a vector. I would like to calculate `x`, `x.^2`,..., `x.^K`. Is there a function that does this all at the same time? (At the moment I just use a `for` loop)

Comment: All three answers are excellent. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you consider looking at the Vandermonde matrix?  Use [`vander`]( http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vander.html).  MATLAB has this built-in.

Comment: I didn't know about this function... it doesn't seem to be exactly what I need because $K \neq$ length of vector.

Comment: You can extract just the first `k` columns of the Vandermonde matrix... so you could do: `A = fliplr(vander(x)); A = A(:,1:k);`  The duplicate post linked has this as a solution.  I should have checked their first!

Comment: Yes, thanks... I landed up using bsxfun(@power, x,1:k) but your solution also works.

Comment: `bsxfun` is the more efficient solution.  If you look at `vander`, it has a lot of unnecessary overhead.  `bsxfun` all the way!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the function `bsxfun` to compute the expansion:

```
  k = 3;
  x = transpose(1:10);
  P = bsxfun(@power, x,1:k);
```

Answer (score 5):

The following may be more efficient in terms of required operations, because for computing each *x*^*n* it applies multiplication instead of power, by reusing the previously computed *x*^(*n*-1):

```
x = 1:10; %// row vector
K = 5; %// maximum power
result = cumprod(repmat(x, K, 1), 1);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use meshgrid.

```
k = 1:10;
[X, K] = meshgrid(x, k);
Y = X.^K; %or Y = power(X,K);
```

Comment: Nice alternative, but probably prohibitive for larger sized vectors and values of `k`.